# How to set a watch point for an instance variable?

Tags: c++, gdb, breakpoints

My class is defined in a header file, and I need to watch for its private non-static member in GDB, like this:

```
class foo {
    int bar;
};
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set watchpoint on memory address.

You should stop in your code somewhere after `foo` constructor execution and print `bar` variable address.
Then you can set watchpoint on address like this:

```
(gdb) p &bar
$1 = (int *) 0x10793ad0
(gdb) watch *0x10793ad0
```